# what should be peer dependencies when creating libs in webpack?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, package.json

We're creating reusable react components. Each component is wrapped as a npm lib with webpack.
Should each one of these libs mark its dependencies as peer dependencies and expect the application to install them when using it? Or, should they be regular dependencies? In that case- are we risking duplicate node modules?
A good examples would be react-
1. a component we wrap as a lib requires react
2. the app using this lib requires react
Should react be a peer dependency or dependency in the lib?

Answer (score 2):

React/ReactDOM definitely needs to be a peer dependency. If set in dependencies and the user has a different version installed than you specify bad things can happen.

Their project can end up with two separate versions of react installed. This can wreck havoc on build tools, code editors and react itself.

Comment: ok, that was our thoughts. Now what about other libs which are used by the component? Libs that the aren't necessarly used by the consuming app? what's a good way to decide if should be packed with the lib or shouldn't?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. For something like react, you'll almost always want it to be a peer dependency. This is because

- if you're importing a component from another package, you pretty much have to be using react yourself to render it
- having two copies of react loaded will cause errors.

So in situations like this, you definitely want to use a peer dependency to protect yourself from ever having more than one copy of the dependency in your bundle.

For other dependencies though, it may not be necessary. For instance, if you have a dependency and your app that both depend on a utility function package, it's fine for both to just have it as a regular dependency. Assuming you are specifying the dependency with a ^, your package manager (npm, yarn) will handled deduping the dependency, so the only way you end up with two copies at build time is if they depend on different semver major versions. If your app and your dependency are using the common package independently, that should be okay.

So basically, the question you want to ask yourself when deciding to make something a peer dependency is, 'do I need to prevent there from ever being two different versions of this package (make it a peer dependency), or is it okay if there are (normal dependency)?'